# How to Group and Split Monad Transformers using Identity

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, megaparsec

I am currently learning about Monad Transformers and noticed that the [`MonadTrans` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#t:MonadTrans) that the library I am using ([Mageparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-9.2.1/docs/Text-Megaparsec.html#t:ParsecT)) implements, does not define any way to `group` and `split` apart the Transformer, where I would expect these functions to both exist and have this signature.

```hs
group:: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => t Identity (m a) -> t m a
split:: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => t m a -> t Identity (m a)
```

... And be defined as inverses of each other.
The reason I was expecting some functions like this to be defined, is because without them I have no clue how I would define `group $ f <$> split tmx <*> split tmy`. Not that they would be only useful for that!

**To my current knowledge:** `(TransMonadT m) a` is isomorphic to `TransMonad (m a)`

- Do these functions exist within `Control.Monad.Trans`?
- And if not how do I define them in general?
- And if I cannot define them in general, at the very least how do I define them for `ParsecT`?

Comment: `ExceptT e m a ~ m (Either e a)`, so `ExceptT e Identity (m a) ~ Identity (Either e (m a)) ~ Either e (m a)` while `ExceptT e m a ~ m (Either e a)` - which are not interchangeable. `group` and `split` can only be implemented for limited amount of transformers, and I think you cannot define one for ParsecT. IIRC ParsecT is defined via continuations, which is quite an outlier among monad transformers.